# How to use private npm registry for specific module

Tags: javascript, npm

Let's say we have a private registry (sinopia) and we have some private module there call "secret-lib"

What we are doing now is in a `.npmrc` add the  following line:

`registry=http://10.16.1.2:3333/`

and package json:

```
dependancies: {
  "secret-lib": "^0.1.1",
}
```

However this makes that every other modules also being proxied through the private registry.

Is there a way to only go through the private registry when is fetching `secrete-lib`?

Additional information: The `secret-lib` also in a private repo managed by Lerna, so I cannot just do something like below because that's not the published module

```
dependancies: {
      "secret-lib": "git@my-company.io:libs/secret-lib.git^0.1.1",",
    }
```

Comment: Is not the same that was asked here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38499150/308341

Comment: @juanpicado, no this is not the same.

Comment: @kossel, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @JamieHill no, not yet, we are still using going through the private repo for everything