# How to config several private repository and public repository in npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to run npm install and to have multi repositories to get dependencies.
The logic that I want first to look on public Nexus and just if it didn't find the artifact look for my private Nexus.

I add `.npmrc` for this

```
registry=https://myRepo1.....
strict-ssl=false
https-proxy
```

Do I need to add the public npm repository also? What is the url for this ?
Lets assume that I have also another registry how I can add it also ? ( for example https://myRepo2 )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to setup a private NPM proxy registry such as [Verdaccio](http://www.verdaccio.org/). You can configure your `.npmrc` to use your Verdaccio registry instead of npmjs.org and when you `npm install` or `yarn add` a module your private registry will be searched first, if the module isn't in your private registry it will then look in a configured upstream or "uplink" registry. You can configure multiple uplink registries as shown here: http://www.verdaccio.org/docs/en/uplinks.html

Comment: can I use .npmrc and not Verdaccio ? does Verdaccio is open source ?

Comment: could you give me an example for this ?

Comment: Hi, here a verdaccio maintainer. Verdaccio is being licensed MIT and completely open source. One of the main features we call then uplinks and you can visualize how it works here http://www.verdaccio.org/docs/en/uplinks.html