# Private and Public NPM Package Install in Single Command

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a few npm package listed in package.json file , some are public and some are private. I want to install both types of packages in single command by using `npm install`.

If npm registry set on global, private package shows `404`, so how to achieve this by single command.I want Both types of package install on node_modules.

Comment: As far as I'm aware this isn't possible without one of the following:
- a private registry that falls back to the public registry if the package isn't found
- a registry proxy like Verdaccio (more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48417082/how-to-config-several-private-repository-and-public-repository-in-npm/48417335#48417335)

Answer (score 3):

The faster solution is what @hugomarisco suggested in the comment section. I'll assume your private package is in any registry (A) and the remainings are fetched from npmjs (B).

To make it more clear, you can use [verdaccio](http://www.verdaccio.org/docs/en/uplinks.html) and set up your multiples registries as uplinks as is visualized here.

[image]

Your uplink configuration might look like this,

```
uplinks:
  npmjsA:
   url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
  registryB:
    url: http://mirror.local.net/
```

and then just define the package access to each remote by patterns

```
packages:
  'my-private-*':
     access: $authenticated
     publish: $authenticated  
     proxy: registryB    
  '**':
     access: all
     publish: $authenticated
     proxy: npmjs
```

In such way, you can access your private packages safely while **verdaccio** fetch for you those belong any public registry as npmjs.

In your terminal just do

```
npm set registry http://localhost:4873 
npm install
```

and you are set. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

After did all experiment, i up all my private package to server as a scoped package. like as `@private/jsonwrite`, `@private` is my scoped name. then i write below config in `.npmrc`

```
@private:registry=https://npmjs.my-private-repo.net
```

then just run `npm install`, it works both on remote and global package. Which is scoped package download from `.npmrc` given link and rest of others from global npm.

Answer (score 0):

`npm --usercofig=./.npmrccorp i` :  This will install the modules as mentioned in `package.json` while considering the configuration file supplied by the `--userconfig` argument. The last `i` and `install` are interchangeable. This can be rewritten as `npm --usercofig=./.npmrccorp` install also

To install both private and public packages with single `npm --usercofig=./.npmrccorp i` command you need to maintain both the `dependencies` in `package.json` dependencies node and then there should be a .npmrccorp file containing your authentication token as follows:

**package.json**:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@org/package1": "^1.0.14",
    "@org/package2": "^1.0.0",
    "public package1": "^1.5.0",
    "public package1": "^2.117.0",
   }
}
```

**.npmrccorp**

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=a*******-****-****-****-***********1 (32 bit authentication token)
```

Comment: For this to work  there should be a `.npmrccorp`  file containing private modules at the root path of the project. is it present?

Comment: yeah at present, can u share your. nprccorp in github gist. that should be helpful to me.