# ng-add & npm link - how to mock npm registry

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am developing a schematics collection for `@angular/cli`. I would like to test locally how it is working.

Is it possible to test `ng-add` CLI feature locally?

After linking project with `npm link` and running `ng add myFeature`, `@angular/cli` tries to download the desired library from the npm, what causes following issue:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: myLibrary@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mtreder/.npm/_logs/2018-05-09T10_13_58_291Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
Package install failed, see above.
```

Can I somehow mock, npm registry to my local environment?

Comment: If you've `npm link`ed the library, why are you trying to `ng add` it, too? You wouldn't `npm link` a library, and then `npm install` it. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `verdaccio` to mock a local registry and publish your own stuff and resolve the remaining dependencies from npmjs.

https://www.verdaccio.org/

Here some answer might helpful for you.

[Private and Public NPM Package Install in Single Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49658225/private-and-public-npm-package-install-in-single-command/49769042#49769042)

I'm not sure whether this 100% answer your question, but, I hope it helps.