# how to add registry in npm install for scope package

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to run npm insatll with registry but with scope
for example
@test:registry=url

I tried

```
npm install --registry @test url
npm install --registry@test url
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Perhaps you need to  [Associate the scope with the registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope#associating-a-scope-with-a-registry) at login. The docs say _"Once a scope is associated with a registry, any `npm install` for a package with that scope will request packages from that registry instead"_

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633678/is-there-any-way-to-configure-multiple-registries-in-a-single-npmrc-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to configure multiple registries in a single npmrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633678/is-there-any-way-to-configure-multiple-registries-in-a-single-npmrc-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working for me, you can run **npm --registry http://url**

or Verify that your registry is set correctly by **npm config get registry**

if not run

**npm config set registry http://url**

Comment: I want to add scope package not all the registry but only the @test

Comment: I need to run npm install with registry

Comment: try npm --registry http//url install your dependency name

Comment: i didn't understand it