# Using multiple private packages from npm

Tags: node.js, npm

We are currently using a private npm package in our project and we would like to use another private npm package in the same project. Both of our packages are created from members from our company who belong to different teams. For example, lets say we are using the private package @team_1/database and like to use the package @team_2/wrapper as well. The .npmrc allows us to have only one authToken in it. Is there any way for us to use both private packages using different authentication tokens without adding the packages under the same private account? Adding both authTokens in the .npmrc file won't do the job.

Comment: Looks like a dup of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633678/is-there-any-way-to-configure-multiple-registries-in-a-single-npmrc-file

Comment: Both of the packages are at the same registry ---> registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/ . The issue that you pointed out is about having multiple registries. I want to use multiple private packages from the same registry, and in order to do that I need multiple authTokens in the .npmrc

Comment: Good question and I am looking for an answer as well. Until now I think it's not possible unfortunately. Did you find a solution to this problem?