# Install an npm module from a private GitHub repository using GitHub Actions

Tags: node.js, github, npm, github-actions

I am trying to run a build for a Node.js project using GitHub Actions. As part of the `npm install`, I need to install an npm module directly from a private GitHub repository (not from GPR!).

In the `package.json` I have:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "my-module": "github:<org>/<my-module>#master",
  ...
},
```

However, when running `npm install`, I get:

> npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
>   npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

The repository is part of my own organization, and locally (i.e. from my machine) it works. How can I make this run?

I have already tried setting the `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN` environment variable, but it didn't make a difference. Although you find this suggestion quite often, it seems to only address GPR. What I would like to avoid is having to hardcode the token into the `package.json` file. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install private github repositories by dependency in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210437/npm-install-private-github-repositories-by-dependency-in-package-json)

Comment: More specifically, this answer in the above linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312033/2089675

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what didn't work, but you may also want to try changing the url that you use for the repo. From the error message you are getting, it looks like npm is trying to resolve the url, using ssh instead of http(s). In that question page I linked, some answers show a different syntax for working with http(s) urls and this may aid in ensuring that the github token is used rather than expecting an ssh key

Answer (score 40):

This is how I have managed to install dependencies from private GitHub repositories.

Dependencies in package.json can be added as follows. The `github:` prefix is optional. Specifying the `#branch` or `#tag` is also optional.

```
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "myrepo": "username/myrepo#master",
        "myotherrepo": "github:username/myotherrepo"
    },
```

Here is an example workflow. `PAT` is a `repo` scoped [Personal Access Token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line). It is important to disable persisted credentials on `actions/checkout`, otherwise they will override your `PAT`. Note that the `git config` change persists between steps so you only need to run it once per job.

```
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          persist-credentials: false
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12.x
      - run: git config --global url."https://${{ secrets.PAT }}@github.com/".insteadOf ssh://git@github.com/
      - run: npm ci
      ...
```

Comment: works like a charm, this is very useful in case a project has modules but the source is github private repos and not NPM

Comment: prefixing a package with `github:` doesn't work at all

Comment: Thanks! that work like a charm, including the `github:` prefix. I will also mention that one needs to create the `PAT` secret in the repository secrets

Comment: @peterevans God bless you, my dude
My package file was already using HTTPS URL to the private repo so I changed the ssh://git@github.com/ to https://github.com in the answer and it worked like a charm

Comment: Which OAuth scopes do I need to define on the PAT I create for this to work? `public_repo`? Or perhaps `read:packages`? I'm surprised not to see a scope called `private_repo` or something like that…

Comment: I followed this and it says `npm ERR! remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.`

Comment: `git config --global url."https://github-actions:${{ secrets.TOKEN }}@github.com/".insteadOf ssh://git@github.com/`
This worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

A very straightforward solution that requires only **read-only** access to the repo. Uses GitHub's Deploy Keys and the following action https://github.com/webfactory/ssh-agent

##### 1. Provide a private repo in `package.json` in the following format:

```
"dependencies": {
    "repo": "git+ssh://git@github.com:user/private_repo.git",
}
```

##### 2. Generate a deploy key locally on your machine. Use empty passphrase

```
ssh-keygen -f my_key
```

##### 3. Create a deploy key via GitHub UI (prefer read-only). Use contents of `my_key.pub`

[image: Deploy keys]

##### 4. Create a GitHub Actions secret named `REPO_SSH_KEY` for the target repo via GitHub UI - the one that will be running GitHub Actions. Use contents of `my_key` – it is a private key

[image: SSH secret]

##### 5. Update the GitHub Actions workflow file to look like this

```
# ...
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Add SSH key to chekout a private repo
        uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.4
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.REPO_SSH_KEY }}

      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      # ...
      # the rest of the steps, including npm install
      # that will successfully access the private repo
```

Comment: This is how it should be done and why there are deploy keys in the first place

Answer (score 1):

From the error and the way you've included the dependency (in package.json), it seems you are not passing authentication credentials (token, ssh.

Refer to this documentation for specifics on [Git URLs as Dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies)

It can be done via https and oauth or ssh.

**https and oauth**: [create an access token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) that has "repo" scope and then [use this syntax](http://rzrsharp.net/2013/07/02/private-github-repos-with-npm-and-heroku.html):

```
"package-name": "git+https://<github_token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git"
```

or

**ssh**: Setup ssh and then use this syntax:

```
"package-name": "git+ssh://git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git"
(note the use of colon instead of slash before user)
```

Comment: You can use `x-oauth-basic` approach but make sure to add `persist-credentials: false` to the checkout action as mentioned in a response above.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me. Create a npmrc file in root with the builtin `GITHUB_TOKEN` from secrets.

```
  - name: Create .npmrc
    run: echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" >> .npmrc
```

I also needed to allow read access to the repository using the action from the private repository via `Manage Actions access` for the `GITHUB_TOKEN` to work. AFAIK the `GITHUB_TOKEN` is scoped to the current repository. Otherwise you can pass a PAT (Personal Access Token) with read packages permissions as an action secret as well.

I'd assume the same would need to be done if you use `actions/setup-node@v3` to create the npmrc. Or if you pass it as an env var.

[Access Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmBPw.png)

Answer (score -3):

You should edit your `.npmrc` file.
You can also use `npm config`

`npm config set @myco:registry http://reg.example.com`

Please see the following thread for more information:
[Is there any way to configure multiple registries in a single npmrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633678/is-there-any-way-to-configure-multiple-registries-in-a-single-npmrc-file)