# Register multiple public packages in npm

Tags: npm, gitlab, package, registry

I'm trying to use my own packages using GitLab, the target is to download multiple packages in my project installing these packages, if I use a single package registry by id project like this, it'll work in -> .npmrc file:

> @despliegue:registry=https://{URL}/api/v4/projects/{ID_PROJECT}/packages/npm/
> //{URL}/api/v4/projects/{ID_PROJECT}/packages/npm/:_authToken={TOKEN}

and then run the command in the project path:

> npm i @despliegue/{PACKAGENAME}

Now I can use tha package normally but I saw several questions and using the instance level like this in order to install all my packages with these two configuration lines in .npmrc file:

> @despliegue:registry=https://{URL}/api/v4/packages/npm/

> //{URL}/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken={TOKEN}

It won't work when I run the command:

> npm i @despliegue/{PACKAGENAME}

returns a 404 not found response, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633678/is-there-any-way-to-configure-multiple-registries-in-a-single-npmrc-file), but I couldn't get it working