# can't install npm moules from gitlab private repo

Tags: gitlab, npm-install

so I have access to gitlab private repo. but when I try to install npm modules from it all I get was errors, it did not even ask me for password and username on gitlab. there's the code https [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/roberto68/846a0eabe9908bb440d5)
and http [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/roberto68/c6edae4ffae067c78f38) when I installed some modules from github it went fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install npm module from gitlab private repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988876/install-npm-module-from-gitlab-private-repository)

Comment: Please add the code to the question. Some of our folks here on STO view questions from tablets or mobile phones, from which is annoying opening several links just to understand one question.

Comment: ok whole problem was I forget to do npm init. I was treating it like a git repo in the back of my mind and then I realized the actual cause