# install dependency from a particular folder on gitlab private repo

Tags: git, gitlab, npm-install

I'm trying to install a custom library from gitLab.

The folder structure looks like the following:

my-lib: (git root)
+dist
--->actual npm lib
+src
+assets
+blabla

As you can see, the actual package is sitting inside dist folder, and the rest is my source code for building this library.

I did follow this post([Install npm module from gitlab private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988876/install-npm-module-from-gitlab-private-repository)), and called
 `npm i git+ssh://git@{my-repo}:{group-name}/{project-name}.git#{branch}`

This does work, but it's getting the source code as well. As a result, if I want to use this lib in my project, I have to import it like `import ** from 'my-lib/dist'`.

My question is how to tell npm, fetch from this dist folder rather than from the root.

Thanks

Comment: for anyone looking for the answer, 
import ** from 'my-lib/dist' may produce a module not found error