# Import components outside the root folder with babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have multiple projects in react in a monorepo: `app1` `app2` `app3`, and each app is built with webpack and babel.

I want to create a shared directory with shared components between the apps, so I created in the monorepo another directory `shared`.

( I executed in each project `npm i ../shared` )

But when I import componets from `shared` inside one the of the apps, babel throws an exception: `Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation. If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.`

**NOTE**: if I import simple functions from `shared` it works, only when importing components it does not work.

What configuration can I add so I can create a shared directory with shared components?

The `.babelrc` file I have in each app looks like this

```
{
   "presets": [
    [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
            "targets": {
                "browsers": ["chrome >= 50"]
            },
            "useBuiltIns": "usage",
            "corejs": 3
        }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx", "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears, this is more of a `webpack` and less of a `babel` problem. The error  pops up, because your `babel-loader` is not configured correctly.

When adding "external folders/modules" to your build, you usually want to do (or at least check) the following:

1. Add the `shared` folder's `src` folder to your `babel-loader`'s `include` (if it is not already included)

   - -> This makes sure, things get babel'ed nicely, and your `preset-react` will actually work).
   - -> Make sure not to include too much (e.g. never include any `node_modules` folder in its entirety, or things will slow down abysmally).
2. You might also have to add the `shared` folder to your `babel-loader`'s [babelrcRoots](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#babelrcroots), because else, it will ignore its `.babelrc.js` file (if it is different from your `babel-loader`'s default config), and thus only use default settings, ignoring your `preset-react`.
3. Often times, you also need to add the `shared` folder's `src` folder to your webpack.config's `resolve.modules`:

   - -> This allows `webpack` to do it's resolve magic inside that folder as well.
   - If it has its own `node_modules`, also add that to `resolve.modules`.
   - For more info on this particular issue, see [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8824#issuecomment-475995296).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a link to an external package:
[Installing a local module using npm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18778516/10441671)

Another possibility if you are working in a team is the more sophisticated approach:
[Get npm module via Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988876/install-npm-module-from-gitlab-private-repository)

As for the declarations of the plugins, see documentation (you need a "plugins" array, see link):
[babel js plugins](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins/)

Comment: I linked to the `shared` package, but it still throws the exception. It seems that the problem is relevant to the babel, isn't it?

Comment: The error message is saying you have configured your plugins incorrectly. You need a "plugins" array there. See readme: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins/ - I have updated the answer

Comment: I tried it already, it didn't work. I tried to install the plugin `@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx` and add it to the plugins array (as the exception explained), but it didn't work either

Comment: I don't see a `plugins` section in your posted configuration. Please update the question with your plugins section.

Comment: Updated the post :)